Getting Klocwork Error while using std::hex and std::dec
Recently while using std::hex and std::dec I am getting below Klocwork Error in below code.
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void func(std::stringstream& s)
{
    std::string name="str";
    int val[2]={'0', '1'};

    s << "\n" << name << ": " << std::hex << "\t";

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(val); i++)
    {
        s << val[i] << " ";
    }

    s << "\n" << std::dec;

    std::cout << s.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::stringstream s;
    func(s);
}

Can anyone help in this how I can resolve this issue.
Klocwork Errors
CWARN.FUNCADDR (2:Error) Analyze
Address of function 'hex' is used instead of a call to this function

CWARN.FUNCADDR (2:Error) Analyze
Address of function 'dec' is used instead of a call to this function


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h - include the right headers, and if the tool still complains see if you can report a bug on it

What is key ? please post a [mre].

A side note: Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?.

This looks like a bug in Klocwork to me.

@wohlstad Corrected the Code

@Mat With Proper Headers also tool still complaining

@n.m.couldbeanAI Should It be Reported then ?

It is true that std::hex is a function. And that a pointer to that function is passed to operator<<, which then calls it. This is normal usage for this kind of function.

I'd say yes, it should be reported.

Also, std::hex and std::dec are among the select few standard functions that are allowed to have their address taken, precisely so pointers to them can be passed to operator<<.
